# A player/script which can show Image video and TV

Tags: linux, software-rec

I am looking for a script/player which can display Images, Videos, output of a TV, and some sort of ticker (text going from left to right or right to left).

All this components should be displayed within one window.

Answer (score 1):

What is it you're trying to do?  I kind of doubt there's a ready-made tool to do this, but there are a few frameworks that possibly enable you to create what you're looking for (with a little learning, a little work and hopefully some fun).

Depending on your preferences and prior knowledge, one or the other of these might be useful for you:

**[Processing](http://processing.org/)**, *"an open source programming language and environment for people who want to create images, animations, and interactions"*; Java-like.

If you prefer C++, have a look at **[openFrameworks](http://www.openframeworks.cc/)**, *"an open source C++ toolkit for creative coding"* (which can [embed Lua](https://github.com/danomatika/ofxLua)).

And there is **[Pure Data](http://puredata.info/)**, *"a real-time graphical programming environment for audio, video, and graphical processing"*, which with GEM also allows for graphical output (see [this flossmanual part](http://en.flossmanuals.net/pure-data/video-gem-tutorials/basics/)).

There's also **[Cinder](http://creativity-online.com)**, *"a community-developed, free and open source library for professional-quality creative coding in C++"*, which doesn't seem to have Linux support, though (*boo hoo*)

There're a lot more projects like these (e.g. if Python's your thing, I doubt there hasn't been done something similar with Python), just have a look in this niche.

### **Edit**

From your comment, I'd advise another way to tackle the problem:  Use a stripped down X11 desktop, with a simple window manager (or none at all, using [`geometry` settings](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Guide_to_X11/Starting_Programs#Specifying_window_geometry)) and tools for the various tasks, e.g.

- VLC (or MPlayer, Xine, ...) to display the TV card output and/or videos
- some image viewer to cycle (if that's what you want) trough your images
- (something for the marquee... hmm... no idea, sorry)

And **have a close look at [Webconverger](http://webconverger.org/)**.  If you've got money to spend, look at Webconverger's [Neon](http://neon.webconverger.com/).  (There might be a lot more to say about [digital signage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_signage) solutions, but I only know of this one.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I want to build a digital signage front end application which can render all the medias (images, videos, output of TV tuner card, and a scrolling text) on a single screen

Comment: Thanks again for the prompt reply. The location of videos and images are not fixed. There will be a template coming from centralized server for the exact location of component, 

Any idea Which language(s) could be used for controlling the placement of this components?

Comment: The Neon seems like a Product itself, we would need source code for customization..

Comment: There're probably many alternatives (I don't know about); a quick search brought up [Xibo](http://xibo.org.uk/) (Open Source) and [this potentially interesting article](http://www.digitaldraw.com/author.asp?section_id=2192&doc_id=247496) ("Open Source hits the Digital Signage Market")